# getting first class content

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

i have several class with a name, how can getting content first class.

```
like:
<div class="hi">
<div class="hey"><input name="hello1"></div> // this is 1
<div class="hey"><input name="hello2"></div> // this is 2
<div class="hey"><input name="hello3"></div> // this is 3
</div>

only getting: class number 1 // <input name="hello1">
```

how is it with jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/bc7dr/)

```
// Pure JavaScript
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('hey');
els[0].innerHTML;

// jQuery
$(".hey:eq(0)").html();
$(".hey").eq(0).html();
$(".hey:first").html();
$(".hey").first().html();
$(".hey:first-child").html();
```

***Note:** In jQuery, selecting by class is usually one of the slowest methods.  It's faster to select by element.className (eg `div.hey`), but really, selecting by ID is the quickest (not "element#id", just "#id").  Hope this helps*

Answer (score 2):

If you want the html content of the first div with class 'hey', try this:

```
var firstChildContent = $('div.hey:first-child').html());
```

Comment: Your answer actually corrected me, I thought it was `.hi:first-child`, but you were right it's `.hey:first-child` ~thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div.hey:eq(0)').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector

```
$('.hey:first').html(); // this is shorter (but less performant)
$('.hey').filter(':first').html(); // this is more performant (based on jQuery documentation)
```

or use the [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method

```
$('.hey').first().html();
```

or use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a specific index

```
$('.hey').eq(0).html(); // first element in the group using a 0-based index
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('.hey:eq(0)').html()

to access hello 1

similarly

> $('.hey:eq(1)').html()

to access hello 2

and

> $('.hey:eq(2)').html()

to access hello 3

Answer (score 0):

```
var hey = document.getElement('.hey');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old question, but for those who find it by Google as I did: you can use *document.querySelector* if you do not support IE8 and lower:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.hey');
el.innerHTML;
```

Or even better you can use it on parent element:

```
// let's say that hi element has id instead of class
var parent = document.getElementById('hi'); 
var el = parent.querySelector('.hey');
el.innerHTML;
```

This is better than using getElementsByClassName because the browser don't need to search for all the classes in the document. So it should be also faster.